# {expect} - how to create the variable's name within a loop after (flight) take-off?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, expect

This is the full script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set a1 "aaa"
set a2 "bbb"
set a3 "ccc"

for {set b 1} {$b<4} {incr b} {
   send a$b
}
```

the output is:

```
 a1a2a3
```

what i wanted was the values for

```
$a1
$a2
$a3
```

how to fix ?

someone recommended "eval"

```
   eval send "a$b"
```

which does not seem to be working, outputs same thing as above.

Comment: Sorry. What do `javascript` and `python` have to do with this?

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, do they make you have to post comments and ask that question to people that make errors with tags ? there has to be something more practical, such as a down vote and move on

Comment: "*Drive-by*" down-votes are generally frowned upon as they're not usually helpful. But, tags should be used when they [describe the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) so users with [experience with the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/topusers) are more likely to see your question.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, it's already sad once that programmers are wasting their lives giving away free codes to people on here, if they have to ask people and try to tame them, that's sad times 2, it's a super emo story, the universe may be godless, it's important we understand "helping each other" might not even be regarded as something "divine" by the "universe" and beyond.

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, concepts such as `being frowned upon of` can easily be converted into re-usuable energy. a force is a force regardless of what type of force it might be. any motion can be converted into re-usable energy,. someone might like being `frowned upon of` becuse it's a form of force that can be converted into energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you want an [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/array.htm):

```
array set myarr {
    a1 "aaa"
    a2 "bbb"
    a3 "ccc"
}

foreach {var value} [array get myarr] {
   puts "Color: $var Count: $value" 
}
```

This code outputs this for me:

```
Color: a3 Count: ccc
Color: a1 Count: aaa
Color: a2 Count: bbb
```

So they don't actually have an order.

Or it could be that you're looking for a [list](http://wiki.tcl.tk/440):

```
set mylist {"aaa" "bbb" "ccc"}
lappend mylist "ddd" 

foreach elem $mylist {
    puts $elem
}
```

This will output exactly:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

[This page](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tanja/Lectures/JRTkDoc/JanusBasics/BasicTcl.html) should make such things pretty clear for you

Comment: thank you so much, will choose this answer soon as permission to choose an answer is granted, may i ask which tag brings you here with this answer ?

Comment: ``bash`` tag brings me here. Please note that this is not actually an array like in other languages. Hold on, I am still editing the answer

Comment: @Lexicographer Another great tag for this question is ``tcl`` because ``expect`` is an extension to ``tcl`` language.